# Get the maximum number between two columns and a label them in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which has two columns; Women and Men, and I want to get the maximum value and then label the respective value.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'WOMEN':[0,1,3,1,2,0,0],
                 'MEN':[2,3,1,2,0,0,1]})
```

The objective is to create a new column called 'sex' that has the maximum value between 'women' and 'men'; for example, in the first case, the result value should be 2, from the respective value from 'MEN', the following step I need, I would to label the data origin, I mean, at the end, I don't need the value, I need to label from the origin value as 1 to MEN and 0 to WOMEN.

For the following case, the second, the maximum origin value is 3 from MEN, that value should go to the new column 'sex' but I want to label it as '1' and finally if the values are equal, I would like that the labeled value would be random either 0 or 1.

I left a table to illustrate the final result

| id | WOMAN | MEN | SEX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

remember that men:1 and woman:0

Thanks for your support

Comment: `df['SEX'] = df['MEN'].ge(df['WOMAN']).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2):

Simply compare the columns' values and convert the resulting boolean to integer:

```
df['SEX'] = df['MEN'].gt(df['WOMEN']).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   WOMEN  MEN  SEX
0      0    2    1
1      1    3    1
2      3    1    0
3      1    2    1
4      2    0    0
5      0    0    0
6      0    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x[0]>x[1] else 1, axis = 1)
```

Result:

```
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
dtype: int64
```

You use apply with axis = 1 to apply the lambda function on each row of the df. The lambda here is just using the conditional expression on x[0] (0th column - woman) and x[1] (1st column - men).